# Selenium IDE - How To Validate For Special Chars In Firstname Field

Tags: c#, selenium

Script to validate the special character in first name field?
Or do not validate for special character in first name field though validate in the field when we submit manually? Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

well you could always execute javascript for the same.

```
selenium.GetEval(@"var regExp=/[`\^=<>|]+/g;
                   return document.getElementById('idOfTheField').value.test(regExp);")
```

Make sure that you right the regex that you need to check for. Hope this helps.